# Update <select> via AJAX success

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have some DropdownLists in my View

Here is code

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Question1", null, "Вопрос 1", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "form-control", @style = "height:40px;margin-bottom: 20px;"})
```

I have AJAX call to add question

Here is code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#save_quest').click(function () {
       savequestion();
      });
});

// Сохранение вопроса в модальном окне
function savequestion() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'Post',
        dataType: 'Json',
        data: {
            Question_new: $('#question').val(),
            Answer: $('#answer').val(),
            Preparing: $('#prepare').val(),
            Retries: $('#retries').val(),
        },
        url: '@Url.Action("CreateNewQuestion", "Questions")',
        success: function (da) {
            if (da.Result === "Success") {
                $('#myModal').hide();
                emails_update();
                } else {
                alert('Error' + da.Message);
            }
        },
        error: function (da) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
}
```

How I can update DropDownList values on sucess?

Thank's for help

Comment: Update DropDown to what?

Comment: values in DropdownList@User3250

Comment: Do you get the new list data after success?

Comment: Seems like no. You can see it from my AJAX call@User3250

Comment: Then how will you get the data to update the Dropdown. Either you return on dropdown data list on success or you will need to make another ajax request to get the data and bind the data to dropdown

Comment: Okay, how I can do this?@User3250

Answer (score 0):

I am attaching a sample showing the controller, view and the jquery code.

*View Code*

```
   @model IC.Models.ReportViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm(actionName: "GetReportFilter", controllerName: "Report", method: FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "edit_form", @id = "frmStatisticsReport" }))
{
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="box box-frame" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
        <div class="box-inner" style="padding-left: 0px">
            <div class="box-caption">Search Statistical Reports</div>
            <div style="padding: 2px;">
                @Html.ValidationSummary()
            </div>
            <ul class="piped font-weight-normal">
                <li>
                    <b>Company: </b>

                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m =>  Model.CompanyId,
                                                        Model.CompanyLookupValues.Select(
                                                            c => new SelectListItem() { Value = c.CompanyId.ToString(), Text = c.CompanyName }
                                                        ),
                                                         "-- select --",
                                                        new { @class = "width-4" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.CompanyId)
                            <text>&nbsp;&nbsp;</text>

                    <b> Report Type: </b>
                     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.ReportId,
                              Model.ReportLookupValues.Select(c => new SelectListItem() { Value = c.ReportId.ToString(), Text = c.ReportName }),
                                "-- select --",
                            new { @class = "width-4" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.ReportId)
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                         <input class="button-primary" type="button" id="btnGetReportFilters" value="&nbsp;&nbsp;Get Report Filters&nbsp;&nbsp;" 
                              onclick="GetFilters();" />
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>


}
```

*View Models used*

```
public class ReportViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Company is a required field")]
        [Display(Name = "Company")]
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ReportCompanyViewModel> CompanyLookupValues { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Report Type is a required field")]
        [Display(Name = "Report Type")]
        public int ReportId { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Report> ReportLookupValues { get; set; }


    }

    public class Report
    {
        public int ReportId { get; set; }
        public string ReportName { get; set; }
    }

    public class ReportCompanyViewModel
    {
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    }
```

*Jquery function for populating the second dropdown*

```
function GetReportTypes() {
    var companyId = $("#CompanyId").val();
    if (companyId != '') {
        var url = '@Url.Action("GetReportTypes", "Report")';
        $.getJSON(url + '?companyId=' + companyId, function (data) {
            var select = $("#ReportId");
            select.empty();
            select.append($('<option/>', {
                value: '',
                text: "-- select --"
            }));

            $.each(data, function (index, itemData) {
                select.append($('<option/>', {
                    value: itemData.ReportId,
                    text: itemData.ReportName
                }));
            });
        });
    }
}
```

*Controller Code*

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var companies = ReferenceDataService.GetFacilitiesForReport().Select(r => new ReportCompanyViewModel { CompanyId = r.Id, CompanyName = r.Name });

            ReportViewModel model = new ReportViewModel
            {
                CompanyLookupValues = companies,                
                ReportLookupValues = new List<Report>()
            };
            return View(model);
        }


 public JsonResult GetReportTypes(int companyId)
        {
            List<Report> reportTypes = new List<Report>();
            if (companyId > 0)
            {

                    reportTypes = ReferenceDataService.GetReportTypes().Select(r => new Report { ReportId = r.ReportId, ReportName = r.ReportName }).ToList();


            }

            return Json(reportTypes, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); ;

        }
```

Comment: It not populating to dropdown

I see only  --select-- and no values